# copyItemAtPath, moveItemAtPath, and createFileAtPath all seem to create a file that's unreadable

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdata, nsurl, nsfilemanager

So I'm trying to figure out why I can't make a copy of my file that's readable. I've tried moveItemAtPath, copyItemAtPath, and createFileAtPath. Each time, reading the data from the original path works fine but reading it from the new file path results in a 0 byte nil NSdata object.

```
NSData* tempData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:tempSoundFile]; // reads just fine

NSError* error;
NSFileManager* fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString* docDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString* uniqueFileName = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@", description.text, [NSDate date]] MD5];
NSString* newAudioFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.caf", docDir, uniqueFileName];

if (LOG) { NSLog(@"Copying %@ to %@", tempSoundFile.path, newAudioFile); }

// Have tried either or both as well as moveItemAtPath with the same result
[fileMgr createFileAtPath:newAudioFile contents:tempData attributes:nil];
//[fileMgr copyItemAtPath:tempSoundFile.path toPath:newAudioFile error:&error];

NSData* audioAfter = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newAudioFile]]; // nil data
```

Log Output:

Copying /var/mobile/Applications/19531C7F-F408-45B9-B417-09315BB15B49/Documents/8554temp.caf to /var/mobile/Applications/19531C7F-F408-45B9-B417-09315BB15B49/Documents/933becb02783c8f9c715acbdca0e15ed.caf

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you've checked the return values of the various file manager methods and they indicate success (return `YES`)? Have you also verified that `[NSURL URLWithString:newAudioFile]` gives the expected results?

Comment: Is `audioAfter` nil, or a valid NSData instance with length 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your last line to:

```
SData* audioAfter = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:newAudioFile]; // NOT nil
```

Because path url with `NSURL` expect a file:// at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks! that's exactly right. The URL was not auto generating the file:// like I assumed it would.